# Question about the coroutine of lua: why the main thread doesn't continue to run when the other thread yield?

Tags: lua

Why the main thread doesn't continue to run when the other thread yield?

You see there is no "hello world" on the terminal.

```
function foo ()
    print("foo" )
    count = 0;
    while( 0<1 )
    do
       count = count + 1;
       print("count=", count);
       if count>5 then
         break
       end
    end

    return coroutine.yield()
  end
  
  co = coroutine.create(function ()
        foo();
        print("hello world")  --why doesn't "hello world" output to the terminal?
        print(type(co))
        return b, "end"
  end)

  coroutine.resume(co)
```

ADDED:
This code snippet(adding one line code) seems work,but I don't fully understand why.

```
function foo ()
    print("foo" )
    count = 0;
    while( 0<1 )
    do
       count = count + 1;
       print("count=", count);
       if count>5 then
         break
       end
    end

    return coroutine.yield()
  end
  
  co = coroutine.create(function ()
        foo();
        print("hello world")
        print(type(co))
        return b, "end"
  end)

  coroutine.resume(co)
  coroutine.resume(co)  --add this line
```

Comment: Also keep in mind that lua coroutines are not real threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `"hello world"` in the console because the coroutine yields befor it is printed.

```
co = coroutine.create(function ()
        foo();  -- <-- coroutine.yield() inside! 
        print("hello world")
        print(type(co))
        return b, "end"
  end)
```

Your coroutine calls `foo()` befor print("hello world"). Inside `foo` you call coroutine.yield.

Therefor your single `coroutine.resume` returns and your program is done.

Adding a second `coroutine.resume(co)` will make `co` continue where it yielded and hence start from `print("hello world")`